# In XML shape, stroke width is set to 1px but it doesn't seem

Tags: android, stroke, android-shape

Here's my XML code:

```
<inset
    android:insetTop="5dp"
    android:insetBottom="5dp"
    android:insetLeft="5dp"
    android:insetRight="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:bottom="15dp"
                android:top="15dp"
                android:left="-100dp"
                android:right="-100dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="#ffaaaaaa" android:width="1px"/>
            <solid android:color="#aad8d8d8"/>
        </shape>
</inset>
```

And this is what it looks like [image] . As you can see in this image, the stroke width is not exactly 1 pixel. I think there's some fading effect in the stroke. On other side, I wonder when I get bitmap of this `View` via `getDrawingCache()`, [image] It seems to be okay.

Can anyone please point me out to the problem? Note that I've tried both `1px` and `1dp` but no luck with the same result. BTW, I tested on my low dpi 7" tablet running Android 4.0.4.

Comment: post the xml where you used this/

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I used this as background for a `TextView`, Is the XML needed?

Comment: For such a simple case, you can try creating a new Drawable to take control of it.